# Display 2 Elements in line, and still able to adjust either element vertically

Tags: html, css

I have 2 inline elements, I would like to shift the logo down a bit, so I need to apply margin-top to it. Somehow, it won't take effect.

```
<div id="block_container">

    <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>  
    <div id="bloc2"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/logos/2012/haring-12-res.png"></div>

</div>
```

---

```
#block_container
{
    text-align:center;
}
#bloc1, #bloc2
{
    display:inline;
}


#bloc2 {

    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/mb0xquko/5/

Answer (score 1):

margin-top will not take effect because you set `display: inline` to the element `#bloc2`

You could change from `inline` to `inline-block` without any margin  applied

```
#bloc1, #bloc2 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or use a [Flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you actually want to achieve, you can make use of `display: flex;` without needing to adjust the image's `margin` or `padding`.

`justify-content: center;` will put it the middle, `align-items: center;` will put both elements on the same line.

```css
#block_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="block_container">

  <div id="bloc1">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</div>
  <div id="bloc2"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/logos/2012/haring-12-res.png"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex box, you can use `display: flex` for container, then use `margin` to each element. pay attention you don't need to use `display` in `#block1` and `#block2`

```
#block_container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#block2{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```